# JS method execute twice when click the button

Tags: javascript, button, controller

In my code I have this button

```
 <div>#{gui.button  onClick:"previewPage()"/}</div>
```

, and when click it I it goes to the function :

```
function previewPage() {
    window.open('@{Controller.previewErrorPage()}, '_blank');
}
```

this method open new tab and show html page.
this function call the controller in the server side .
After that it enter one more time to the same method (previewPage).

which mean when click the button, the previewPage method call twice, and the controller also execute twice, and it open 2 tabs.

```
public void previewPage(ErrorPage errorPage, Long accountId) {
      
        renderHtml(...).toString()));
    }
```

this is the controller that the function called .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately it seems you forgot to ask a question. Please read [ask] and edit your post to actually include a question. Is the code not working as you intended? If so, what's it doing that differs from what you expected it to do?

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter The controller looks like Java.

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper: yes, you're right. I missed that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65396104/mapping-json-to-array-return-null

Answer (score 0):

This may happens when you've binded callback listener (onClick) twice.
Probably you somehow have two same JS imports. Take a look into this.

Answer (score 0):

It was a chrome issue, I restart the settings in chrome, and the problem was solved.
The chrome was stucked, and it was make problems